# Using the right redis data types for time-based comparisons

Tags: redis

In an app I'm writing, users can perform various social actions. I'm saving the results of these actions in **Redis hashes**.

The naming scheme of each hash employs concatenated `user_ids` and corresponding `action_ids`. E.g. `hash:11:99` could be a hash storing results for `user_id` 11 and `action_id` 99. Under this scheme, retrieving results for any action performed by any user is an O(1) process (if both `user_id` and `action_id` is known).

But next, I also need to look up all the results of all actions performed by a user in the last 30 mins (precise `action_ids` unknown). To achieve this, I'm storing action_ids alongwith timestamps in sorted sets designated for every user. E.g. `sorted_set:1` could contain `action_ids` and `timestamps` for `user_id` 1. From here, there's a multi-step process to get all actions performed by a user within the previous 30 mins:

1) In the user's sorted set, use `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` to look up `action_ids` that relate to the last 30 mins. Time complexity O(log(N)+M)

2) Using the retrieved `action_ids`, construct hash names that have to be accessed (i.e. `hash:user_id:action_id`).

3) Iterate over each hash and retrieve the desired result. Time complexity O(n)

---

My question is: how can I fulfill the above requirements with better performance than above? I'm open to re-imagining which Redis data types to use.

Comment: Essentially, what you're doing there, is reimplement what RDBMS can do for last 30 years (or more). One must ask, why don't you just pick the right tool for the job?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: for my particular app, redis performs much faster than Postgresql.

Comment: Even in your second multi-step scenario? With proper indexes and some app-specific tuning, postgres can deliver amazing perf. __And__ you have full power of psql :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: haven't benchmarked the two-step scenario yet (since I haven't built it). Need to confirm from experts (i.e. you folks) if this is the fastest way to do it within the redis universe. Once I have an answer, I'll build it, test it, benchmark it.

Comment: You could put it all in a redis lua script to save back and forth between client and redis

Comment: I do not see myself as redis expert, but your approach looks fine to me. Using sorted set to emulate index is idiomatic, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: will accept that as an answer if you post it, along with any other advice (e.g. musings on a hybrid redis-pg solution).

Comment: @HassanBaig: nah, I'm good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some use cases require **data redudancy**.

If you need to store partial data in these sorted sets instead of just *action identifiers* because this will end up in retrieving the required info in less time than an ordinary look up, Redis won't be who will tell you to don't do it. *Just do it!*

When I said *partial data* I mean that I guess you're storing JSON-serialized objects or data in some other serialization format. Maybe the source object has 12 properties but when you need the latest actions done by some user during the last 30 minutes, you just need to access 4 of those 12 properties. So go for it! Store a serialized object with just 4 properties and also the `id` to be able to get the full object - if required - in the application layer.

Furthermore, redundancy may mean that you can create 4 sorted sets storing that ranking of latest actions with different partial data based on use cases. One case requires 3 properties, other requires 2 properties but they're not the same as the first case, and so on...

Just think that Redis is about indexing data in a very efficient way to access it in a breeze.

AFAIK, relational database indexes work this way too. You can build many indexes with many columns and with all possible combinations against the same data table. With Redis, you can get the same behavior and goal your own way because you decide how to model these indexes!